# How can I expand each key of a Json string into separate row

Tags: azure-data-explorer

In my Azure Data Explorer table, I have a JSON string with a list of key value pairs.
Each key can be different between different rows. And the value of the key is not known ahead of time (i.e. I don't know what are the possible values).

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"270":"2","360":"2","480":"1","540":"1","720":"4"} |
| 2 | {"320":"1","480":"4","1280":"5"} |

Is there a way to `mv-expand` each key into separate row?

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 270 | 2 |
| 1 | 360 | 2 |
| 1 | 480 | 1 |
| 1 | 540 | 1 |
| 1 | 720 | 4 |
| 2 | 320 | 1 |
| 2 | 480 | 4 |
| 2 | 1280 | 5 |

Or find out what are all the possible values of the keys?
i.e [270, 320, 360, 480, 540, 720, 1280]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bag_keys()` function, and, if required, expand its output using `mv-expand`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bagkeysfunction

Comment: This solution works if the original order of the keys doesn't matter, as the order of `bag_keys()` output is arbitrary.
If the original key order must be kept, use `mv-expand bagexpansion=array` instead.